# Migration issue when I add a new migration and it says another table object already exists

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, migration

Cleared the record entry for my last table from the migration table. Deleted the table from the database and removed the latest migration entry.  Ran the app to make sure it was clean and it ran fine.

Added a new migration and then update-database. Got a table already exists error.  Started checking and realized the table they were referring to was in the 'UP' of the Migration entry prior to the new entry.  Commented out the 'UP' create and everything updated as expected.

What did I miss that it did not work on the latest migration entry?  Do not want to make this mistake again.

Thank you in advance,

Steve

Answer (score 0):

You have cleared everything but not the actual migration file in your solution. When you tried to run `Update-Database` it ran the previous migration which is not in `__MigrationHistory` then it ran your current migration which caused the issue.